# Cannot read property 'jqmData' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

please your help in my code i want to make select with filter in J Query Mobile 
i tried the below code and it success to filter the data but when choosing an option it does not return any thing and return this error

```
Cannot read property 'jqmData' of undefined
```

this is the code that i used with the java-script

```
 <form>
    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="select-custom-20">Long list:</label>
        <select name="select-custom-20" id="select-custom-20" data-native-menu="false" class="filterable-select">
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
            <option value="CA">California</option>


        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

and this is the java-script

```
  ( function( $ ) {
function pageIsSelectmenuDialog( page ) {
    var isDialog = false,
        id = page && page.attr( "id" );
    $( ".filterable-select" ).each( function() {
        if ( $( this ).attr( "id" ) + "-dialog" === id ) {
            isDialog = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return isDialog;
}
$.mobile.document

    .on( "selectmenucreate", ".filterable-select", function( event ) {
        var input,
            selectmenu = $( event.target ),
            list = $( "#" + selectmenu.attr( "id" ) + "-menu" ),
            form = list.jqmData( "filter-form" );

        if ( !form ) {
            input = $( "<input data-type='search'></input>" );
            form = $( "<form></form>" ).append( input );
            input.textinput();
            list
                .before( form )
                .jqmData( "filter-form", form ) ;
            form.jqmData( "listview", list );
        }

        selectmenu
            .filterable({
                input: input,
                children: "> option[value]"
            })

            .on( "filterablefilter", function() {
                selectmenu.selectmenu( "refresh" );
            });
    })

    .on( "pagecontainerbeforeshow", function( event, data ) {
        var listview, form;

        if ( !pageIsSelectmenuDialog( data.toPage ) ) {
            return;
        }
        listview = data.toPage.find( "ul" );
        form = listview.jqmData( "filter-form" );
        data.toPage.jqmData( "listview", listview );
        listview.before( form );
    })

    .on( "pagecontainerhide", function( event, data ) {
        var listview, form;
        if ( !pageIsSelectmenuDialog( data.toPage ) ) {
            return;
        }
        listview = data.prevPage.jqmData( "listview" ),
        form = listview.jqmData( "filter-form" );
        listview.before( form );
    });
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: can you console.log your selectmenu and list vars after you defined it ?

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this exact problem with a long selector using the example from [jQuery Mobile for Select Widgets](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/selectmenu-custom-filter/).  The error seems to be version specific.  I was originally using the latest version of JQM (at the time of this writing),

`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js`

if I changed it to version `1.4.2`, the error goes away.  I haven't investigated why, but you might try an earlier version to see if you can get your code to work that way.

Edit:  By changing to the lower version I lost the ability to use the auto-suggest feature, so now I'm debugging to try to figure out what's wrong with the original code.

Looking in the `.prevPage` node, there is no entry for `.jqmData`, not sure why yet.

Answer (score 0):

Change the argument in the **pageIsSelectmenuDialog** function from 'data.toPage' to 'data.prevPage':

```
if ( !pageIsSelectmenuDialog( data.prevPage ) ) {
       return;
}
```

Add input cleanup:

```
form = listview.jqmData( "filter-form" );
$("input", form).val("").trigger("change");
listview.before( form );
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace this line

```
listview = data.prevPage.jqmData( "listview" )
```

With these two lines:

```
listview = data.toPage.find( "ul" );
listview = data.toPage.jqmData( "listview", listview );
```

It resolved the problem for me.  I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.4.5.